# A problem similar to the proof of "strong law of large numbers"

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> $\{X_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is an i.i.d. sequence of random variable with $E(|X_1|^p)<+\infty$ for some $p\in (0,1)$. Show that $$Z_n=\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n^{1/p}}$$ converges a.s. to $0$.

So I took $Y_n=X_n.1_{\{|X_n|<n^{1/p}\}}$. Then I wanted to prove that $\sum_n E(|\frac{Y_n}{n^{1/p}}|)<+\infty$.

So $\sum_n E(|\frac{Y_n}{n^{1/p}}|)=\sum_n \int |\frac{Y_n}{n^{1/p}}| dP=\sum_n \int |\frac{X_n.1_{\{|X_n|<n^{1/p}\}}}{n^{1/p}}| dP<\sum_n P(|X_n|<n^{1/p})$. This is where I am stuck now. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: It doesn't work this way; for instance if $X_n = 0$ for all $n$, then $\sum_n P(|X_n|<n^{1/p})=\infty$

Comment: Ya I understand, so what other way will work here? I appreciate any hint.

Comment: As far as I remember, the proof of this statement is pretty complicated; you can find it for instance in Loève's probability book (Vol. 1).

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following estimate to solve your question.
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1/p}\mathsf{E}[|Y_n|]
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1/p}\mathsf{E}[|X_1|1_{|X_1|<n^{1/p}}]\\
&\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)^{1/p}\int_n^{n+1}\frac1{x^{1/p}}\mathsf{E}[|X_1|1_{|X_1|<x^{1/p}}]\,dx\\
&\le 2^{1/p}\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^{1/p}}\Bigl(\int_0^{x^{1/p}}y\,dF_{|X_1|}(y)\Bigr)\,dx \\
&= 2^{1/p}\int_0^\infty y\Bigl(\int_{y^p}^\infty\frac1{x^{1/p}}\,dx\Bigr)\,dF_{|X_1|}(y)\\
&=\frac{p2^{1/p}}{1-p}\int_0^\infty y^p\,dF_{|X_1|}(y)=\frac{p2^{1/p}}{1-p}\mathsf{E}[|X_1|^p]. 
\end{align}